# shell script log output not generating logfile with date

Tags: bash, shell, date, logging, ksh

I have a shell script that I would like to generate logfiles appending date but for some reason its now working.  But I am seeing the logs generated as "RMAN_backup_L0_date+%m%d%y.out"  instead of actual date.

Seems simple issue.

```
    #!/bin/ksh
# $Header: rman_backup_all_dbs.sh
#

TODAY='date+%m%d%y'
OUTDIR_BASE=/u01/app/scripts
OUTDIR=$OUTDIR_BASE/rman
OUTF=$OUTDIR/logs/'RMAN_backup_L0_'${TODAY}.out

find $OUTDIR/logs/* -type f -name "*.out" -mtime +30  -exec  rm -f {} \;
NLS_DATE_FORMAT="DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"

export OUTDIR OUTF NLS_DATE_FORMAT

if [ -f "$OUTF" ]
then
        rm -f "$OUTF"
fi

{ # output block
echo \
"\n`date` ----------------Beginning of Script------------" \
"\nScript name: $0"

ORACLE_USER=oracle.
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the wrong ticks (`'` instead of `` ` ``). Besides that, a space is missing. Correct:

```
TODAY=`date +%m%d%y`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TODAY=$(date +%m%d%y)
```

use substitution .